# Passing parameter via PageFactory

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

I'm using page-object gem with watir and RSpec to test my web application.
Here is my page object.

```
require 'page-object'

class UserEditPage
  include PageObject
  page_url "#{$context}/user/edit?id=#{@params[:id]}"

  text_field :user_id, name: 'userName'

  text_field :pw, name: 'password'
  text_field :pw_retype, name: 'password2'

  # snip uninteresting stuff

  button :submit, index: 0
end
```

I would like to parameterize `:id` in `page_url` via `PageObject::PageFactory` like this:

```
visit UserEditPage, using_params: {id: 1000} do |page|
# operation on page
end
```

[This document](http://rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/PageObject/PageFactory#visit_page-instance_method) implies that above usage is possible, but I couldn't understand how exactly this is achieved.

Question: how can I pass parameter `id` from visit method to `UserEditPage`?

Running code results in

```
       ***/user/edit_page.rb:8:in `<class:UserEditPage>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from ***/user/edit_page.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

probably because `@params` is nil when evaluating page_url.
Changing `using_params: {id: 1000}` to `id: 1000` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `page_url` needs to be:

```
page_url "#{$context}/user/edit?id=<%=params[:id]%>"
```

Note how the parameters need to be included differently - ie `<%=params[:id]%>` instead of `#{params[:id]}`.

The problem is that the `page_url` is evaluated when the page object class is evaluated. This means that when the class is evaluated, params[:id] must already exist. This is not going to be true when you want to include the parameters dynamically.

The page object gem uses ERB to allow you to create a template, which allows substitution of the params later - ie when calling `visit`.

In summary, when creating a `page_url`:

1. Use string interpolation if the value is known when the page object class is evaluated.
2. Use ERB if the value is to be dynamically specified on visit.

**Working Example**

Below is a working example of the dynamic parameters.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

$context = 'http://testurl.com'

class UserEditPage
  include PageObject

  page_url "#{$context}/user/edit?id=<%=params[:id]%>"
end

include PageObject::PageFactory   
@browser = Watir::Browser.new

visit UserEditPage, using_params: {id: 1000} do |page|
  p page.current_url
  #=> "http://testurl.com/user/edit?id=1000"
end
```

Comment: This eliminate NoMethodError, but still cannot pass parameter. `visit` method goes to `http://xxxx/user/edit?id=`, i.e. no parameter substitution.

Comment: I added a full working example, which I think reflects what you are doing and shows the substitution does work. If you are not getting a substitution I would double-check that (1) in the page_url, you are using `<%=` and not `<%` - the equal sign is important; (2) the hash key in your page_url is exactly the same as that in your visit command; (3) your application is not automatically re-directing you.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. My fault was `<%=params['id']%>`. I think this worth documenting officially.